# How to migrate a git repository from CodeCommit to GitHub?

Tags: git, github, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to migrate a git repository from Aws CodeCommit to Github. Basically I want to have the same repository with all branches and all details but moved to GitHub.

I tried a bunch of things that didn't worked so I thought there's an expert here for which this will be really easy !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a way to do exactly that without using the command line. Github has a feature when you create a new repository to import it from a third party's url.

With login credentials the repository can be imported very easily, all guided by the UI.